# Phonegap Android viewing console logs

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web-inspector

I have this Phonegap application I'm working. Unfortunately, I having problems pertaining to a particular feature at the moment. I tried deploying on any iOS device, the error is present. Though by default, we programmers, should solve this problem right away. But I was wondering how I could see `console.logs("...");` on Android.

I've search for related answers regarding this. Most of the answers mostly suggests I should use WebInspector using [jshybugger](https://www.jshybugger.com/). That won't be a problem unless I will be building the project on a level below API L19 (Kitkat) and maybe as low as API L10 (Gingerbread).

Using the AVD emulator was also a suggestion, yet I can't find a way to boot the emulator properly on my computer. And as we all know, Android Emulator is a hell of a snail compared to iOS Simulator.

Unlike for iOS I could just use the Safari Device Inspector to view the console logs and resources. I was hoping for a similar feature without using [jshybugger](https://www.jshybugger.com/) and can be supported by at most Android API L10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` should appear on the adb, you can see it on eclipse or on android monitor (monitor comes with the android sdk)

Or you can use [this online debugger](http://debug.phonegap.com), it creates a javascript script that you put in your index and then you can see your phone debugger there. You can do it locally too using [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html)